# Android studio - can not launch activity from other class

Tags: android

From `MainActivity` I easily launch my `PictureList` activity.

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String btnTxt = b.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PicturesList.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("category", btnTxt);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

In my `PictureList` class I successfully creating a listView of pictures

```
 adapter = new LazyImageLoadAdapter(PicturesList.this, strings, names, ratings, ids);

 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But in `LazyImageLoadAdapter` I have an onClickListener for every picture from the list and I can't succesfully activate ``PictureView` activity from it.

```
private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    private int position;

    OnItemClickListener(int pos) {
        position = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LazyImageLoadAdapter.this, PictureView.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", ids[position]);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
    }
}
```

Error is like so:

```
Error:(116, 29) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(LazyImageLoadAdapter,Class<PictureView>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual argument LazyImageLoadAdapter cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(actual argument LazyImageLoadAdapter cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
constructor Intent.Intent(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Intent.Intent(Intent) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Intent.Intent() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Could anyone give me some tips or solution for that, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LazyImageLoadAdapter.this, PictureView.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("id", ids[position]);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

To this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PictureView.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("id", ids[position]);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because LazyImageLoadAdapter.this does not return a context.

Try this:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PictureView.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", ids[position]);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
    }
```